# Ajax+php+Кирилица

Tags: ajax, php, кириллица

Собственно в чем проблема: делаю живой поиск по масииву.
За основу взял код с примера http://ajaxs.ru/lesson/ajax/132-zhivoj_poisk.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
        var search = $("#search").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://сайт/search.php",
            data: {"search": search},
            cache: false,                       
            success: function(response){
                $("#resSearch").html(response);
            }
        });
        return false;

    });
});
</script>
```

Сначала проверил обычной формой поиск все работает, но когда использую этот скрипт, у меня в переменную **$search** получаются иероглифы, для примера слово "поиск" имеет вот такой вид "**РїРѕРёСЃРє**" 
файл индекс, поиска, и файл с масиивом имеют кодировку вин-1251, в каждом файле  начале прописано

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");
```

Вот код самого поиска:
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");

```
include_once 'array.php'; 
      if(isset($_POST[search])){
        $search = $_POST['search'];
        $search = addslashes($search);
        $search = htmlspecialchars($search);
        $search = stripslashes($search);
echo $search;

      foreach ( $name as $key => $value ) {
        foreach ( $value as $ke => $valu ) {
            foreach ( $valu as $k => $val ) {
            $l='';
            $l=strlen($search);

            $str = substr($val,0,$l);
            if ($str==$search){
            echo "<a href=\"/names/$ke.html\">$val</a><br>";
            }
            }
        }
      }

   }
```

Как решить данную проблему? а именно коректную передачу запроса!

Comment: Причина в том, что ajax-запросы выполняются в utf8 формате

Answer (score 4, accepted):

всегда, всегда, всегда пользуйтесь utf-8!

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему так
в скрипте вместо data: `{"search": search}`, прописал `data: {"search": encodeURIComponent(search)}`, в скрипте поиска добавил

```
    $search=urldecode($search);
    $search=iconv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1251", $search);
```

может кому пригодится.